# Can't find source of NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, jackson

So I'm sure I'm missing something extremely obvious here, but can anyone see the source of this NullPointerException? It occurs in the line `for(ContactInfo contact: contactArray)`

The relevant code is below:

```
private class DownloadJSONData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContactInfo[]> {

    @Override
    protected ContactInfo[] doInBackground(String... jsonURL) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //Set URL where JSON Data exists
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(jsonURL[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Bind JSON data to ConactInfo Array
        try {
            contactArray = mapper.readValue(url, ContactInfo[].class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(ContactInfo contact: contactArray) {
            //Get URL from each ContactInfo object
            String imageSource = contact.getSmallImageURL();

            //Download bitmaps into bitmapArray
            try {
                bitmapArray.add(downloadBitmap(imageSource));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any variables you see non-instantiated are instantiated as global variables for use in other methods. The only thing I can think of is somehow the mapper method isn't mapping anything into contactArray (which is a ContactInfo[] object.)

Comment: Your comment at the end is the answer. Now, figure out why it's not mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the mapper failed.

If this code fails:

```
contactArray = mapper.readValue(url, ContactInfo[].class);
```

It prints a stacktrace but keeps going.
No checks are done on `contactArray` before the actual loop.
`contactArray` is just most likely null.

Check the logcat for `JsonParseException`, `JsonMappingException` or `IOException`.

Comment: Alright, I just added explicit logging info into my catch statements, I'm getting a JsonMappingException, I'm new to Json, any information on what that specific exception is/how to fix it?

Comment: OK, got it, I think I must have typed a variable wrong in my ContactInfo class as I got it working now once I added in some things that I thought may stop the MappingException.